# :not isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I've created a simple navigation bar that when you click on an item, another  opens under it. to disappear the opened  I wrote:

```
$("#container:not(#navbar)").click(function(){
 $("#mini_navbar_home").hide()
});
```

I wanted to say "wherever on the screen (except the navigation bar) that someone clicked, disappear the #mini_navbar_home", but clicking wherever on the container hides that

it's part of the script if helps:

```
 var navs = new Array("#mini_navbar_home","#mini_navbar_aboutus","#mini_navbar_folan");
 var colors = new Array("#home_t","#aboutus_t","#folan_t");

 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#home_t").click(function(){
   change_bg("#home_t")
   navbar_slide_toggle("#mini_navbar_home")
  });
        .
        .
        .
  $("#container:not(#navbar)").click(function(){
   hide_all()
   change_bg()
  });
 });

 function change_bg(div){
  for(i=0; i<colors.length; i++){
   if (colors[i] != div){
    $(colors[i]).css("backgroundColor", "#8895B7");
   }
  }

  if ($(div).css("backgroundColor") == "rgb(169, 181, 212)"){
   $(div).css("backgroundColor", "#8895B7")
  }
  else {
   $(div).css("backgroundColor", "#A9B5D4")
  }
 }
 function navbar_slide_toggle(div){
  for(i=0; i<navs.length; i++){
   if (navs[i] != div){
    $(navs[i]).hide();
   }
  }
  $(div).slideToggle(0);

 }
 function hide_all(){
  for(i=0; i<navs.length; i++){
   $(navs[i]).hide()
  }
 }
```

by the way, #navabr is nested with #container
i guess my solution will look silly to most of the users :D

Comment: Could you add your full code to http://jsfiddle.net or similar?

Comment: An element has always only one ID. So `#a:not(#b)` is pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* you're saying that you want to hide `#mini_navbar_home` when a click happens on `#container` that is not inside `#navbar`.  This is fairly simple:

```
$('#container').click(function(e){
    var $navbar = $('#navbar');
    if (($navbar[0] !== e.target) && // if the click wasn't on navbar itself
        !$navbar.has(e.target).length // and it wasn't inside navbar
       ) {
        $("#mini_navbar_home").hide() // hide it
    }
});
```

The advantage this has over `stopPropagation` is that this allows you to keep using event bubbling on elements within `#navbar`.  `stopPropagation` would break, for instance, `$('a').live(...)` calls.

Answer (score 0):

The easier way is going to be to capture clicks on the document, and then preventing bubbling on your nav bar. That way, the click event will never reach the document, and your hide function is never triggered. You can extend the list of "blacklisted" elements later, as well, and this solution still works even if you click on an element inside of your mini nav bar.

```
var $mini_navbar_home = $("#mini_navbar_home");
$(document).click(function() { $mini_navbar_home.hide() });
$("#navbar").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
});
```